# jquery animate function execute once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

hi i have a function that execute when a server button click(my function call in click event) this function has simple code i show a div that it hide by default and i change div position but when i execute it once it run properly but when i click second time it dont work .what is the problem

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery("#BtnInsert").click(function () {

        jQuery('.alarm').show(400).animate({ left: '285' }, 600).animate({ top: '410px' }, 600).delay(3000).animate({ top: '475px' }, 600).hide(400).animate({ left: '400px' });
    });

});
```

Comment: You should reset the original position at the end of the animation.

Comment: @Skatox It looks like he already is.

Comment: thanks? but how can i reset it?